# Point.py def getLotteryGame() not storing notes and points

Tags: python

Okay so the code im doing is finally reloading the lottery but its not storing the notes or giving the winnings. The only thing it prints is after the random.shuffle(players) and nothing below that. It doesn't store the notes or give the points. Oh pot, lotteryStart, players, and ratios are outside of class: (players and ratios are both a list, pot = 1 and lotteryStart = time.time()) and for alerts.append(players[m]) im not sure if i have to read the alerts.txt file in the module if it's also in my bot.

This is full code link: http://bpaste.net/show/165884/

```
  def getLotteryGame():
    global pot
    global players
    global lotteryStart
    global ratios
    different = float(time.time() - lotteryStart)
    mins = int((different % Point.HOUR) / Point.MINUTE)
    secs = int(different % Point.MINUTE)
    osecs = 59-secs
    if osecs <= 10:
      if len(players) > 0:
        random.shuffle(players)
        print("Shuffled players") #ONLY THING THAT PRINTS
        for i in range(-2, len(players) - 2):
           if i < 0:
             ratios.append(1 - (i * 0.33)) # ratio > 1
           else:
             ratios.append(1 / (1 + (i * 0.33))) # ratio <= 1
        winnings = [pot * r for r in ratios]
        print(ratios)
        for m in range(1, len(players)):
           notes.store("~lottery~", players[m], "The system has placed you "+Point.ordinal(m)+" in the lottery. The lottery awarded you "+winnings+" P$", time.time())
           print("Stored the notes")
           alerts.append(players[m]) 
           print("Alerts appended")
           point = Point.dPoint[players[m]]
           point, winnings = int(point), int(winnings)
           point = int(point+winnings)
           Point.dPoint[players[m]] = int(point)
           print("done")
        return True
     elif len(players) == 0:
        return True
  elif osecs > 10:
     return False
```

Comment: Minimal test case please =)

Comment: Huh? Minimal test case?

Comment: A smaller program that fails for the same reason. I bet that if you do that: you may find the answer yourself, people will be much more likely to answer you and your question will be much more useful to others.

Comment: Aha I found the error. Its the winnings = [pot * r for r in ratios]

Comment: But I don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: Edit your question, leave only that line of code. Tell what you expect, and what you got. At this point however, I am sure the the one line question has already been answered before.